# uWSGI Returning Empty Response

Tags: django, uwsgi

I have a Django site which I am trying to server via uWSGI. I have started the server like so:

```
uwsgi --emperor .
Ctrl+Z
bg 1
```

(There are two .ini files which point to the test version and production version of the site, serving on 9001 and 9002 respectively)

I then attempt to get my site:

```
curl http://localhost:9002
```

When I do that, I get a message saying the the vassel is loyal but no actual response. The uwsgi.log then contains the following:

```
[pid: 5071|app: 0|req: 2/2] 127.0.0.1 () {26 vars in 357 bytes} [Tue Jul 23 13:20:21 2013] GET / => generated 0 bytes in 1 msecs (HTTP/1.1 302) 2 headers in 96 bytes (1 switches on core 1)
```

No errors are logged.

I should say, this worked fine prior to a reboot so the uwsgi.ini files should be fine.

Any ideas where I should start diagnosing this?

Comment: I can report a similar issue but with an even more basic configuration. Headers are sent properly, but the response body is simply empty. I experience this with Python 3.4 both uWSGI and gunicorn.

Comment: tail the uwsgi log and read it very carefully, its a verbose annoyance but I was able to eventually track down my issue, I was missing the `plugin = python3` stanza from my uwsgi vassal's ini, Which in turn meant my python3 django project wasn't actually being loaded or run correctly,

Answer (score 8):

I had the some problem, it turned out that my wsgi application was returning UNICODE instead of BYTE STRINGS (I was on python3) ; and nothing showed in logs about it...
WSGI expects byte strings in output, never unicode.

In the *callable* of your application instead of `return "string"` you should use `return b"string"` or `return "string".encode("utf-8")`

```
def application(env, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
    # One of the below can be used.
    return "string".encode("utf-8")
    return b"string"
```

You can check http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Python.html#python-3 out for more informaiton on using **uwsgi** with **python3**.

Comment: +1 This helped me. I was getting empty response from python3 virtualenv + uwsgi + nginx stack. `return ["hello world"]` should be `return [b"hello world"]` more info on: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Python.html